# Editor - A Plugin for Datatables

Tags: editor, datatables, jquery-datatables-editor

I would like to know if Editor is free. I came across it today and its so easy to edit, add and style datatables. However, I saw that its hosted on CDN and at the same time has a download version. So I would like to know if its free.

Thanks and looking forward to answers.

Comment: Editor for DataTables is commercial software (look [here](http://editor.datatables.net/purchase/index) for purchase options). A free trial is available (same link as before, requires registration).

Comment: It's not free, but any ideas about making it free? :)...

Answer (score 4):

Datatables Editor is not free. It would be better to use ejbeaty/CellEdit. It's free and you can edit, add and style.

Here's the link: https://github.com/ejbeaty/CellEdit
Try it!